# I want downgrade version of 'react-navigation'

Tags: react-native

I want downgrade version of 'react-navigation' from v4 to v3 with npm.  how to do that?

In documents of react-navigation, there is no install way with version. just `npm install react-navigation`

Comment: npm install react-navigation@3.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should uninstall the latest version

```
npm uninstall react-navigation
```

and then install another version. But this version is deprecated

```
npm install react-navigation@3.13.0
```

P.N. version 3.13.0 as you may know is the last update for version 3 and the most used. But just change the version to whatever you want